# When you type data into a form when is it encrypted?

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, theory

This is a theory based question as  opposed to any code related question.
I'm trying to establish how data is encrypted and differences client side to server side. 
[image]

1. Is the data encrypted when it is added to the database/server?

   2. Or are we just relying on data to be secure due to HTTPS which surely does not apply when the data is transmitted from the form to the database? or does it?
   3. What kind of encryption is mostly used these days?

Comment: Your question has 0 context...

Comment: 1. No. 2. Yes, but the data is transmitted from the form to the HTTP server, and from there to the database, not directly from the form to the database. 3. Whatever TLS decides. Neither [tag:aes] nor [tag:public-key-encryption] has anything to do with it: don't tag indiscriminately. Don't abbreviate 'you' here. This is not a mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

The data is not encrypted in the client. When HTTPS is used all data is encrypted during transport over the Internet. When the server application receives the data is has already been decrypted. If you need to store the data the server app will need to perform that encryption.

By this question it is clear you do not understand security so you are not ready to create a system that needs security. The solution is to hire a security professional to help you seeding the security. Security is very difficult to get correct and your users rely on and expect a secure system, please provide that.